# Why script doesn't work in SQL Server (2005, 2014, ...) the first time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2014

I created a table `Table1` in separate connection

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Column1] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

then I add rows in Column1 in a same connection

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1]([Column2])VALUES('abc')
```

After that, in other connection I try to add Column2 and update it

```
alter table Table1 
   add Column2 VARCHAR(20) NULL

update Table1 
set Column2 = 'a'
```

but get an error **Invalid column name 'Column2'.**

then trying add **GO** keyword

```
alter table Table1 add Column2 VARCHAR(20) NULL
go
update Table1 set Column2='a'
```

and get a success message **(1 row(s) affected)**

when I drop column Column2 and trying execute **without** keyword **GO**(
Column2 **does not exists**, dropped)

```
alter table Table1 add Column2 VARCHAR(20) NULL
update Table1 set Column2='a'
```

I get a success message **(1 row(s) affected)**

Why ?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the first part of your question, you get an error because SQL Server is attempting to compile the *batch* you've submitted. At the point in time it tries to compile the batch, which contains an `ALTER TABLE` and an `INSERT` statement, `Table1` doesn't contain `Column2`, and so it cannot compile the `INSERT` statement.

[`GO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) is the *batch separator* used by SQL Server client tools. It causes the client tool to submit your script as two separate batches. In this case, when it's compiling the second batch, which only contains the `INSERT`, the first batch (which contained the `ALTER TABLE`) has already been compiled and executed, and so this time, `Table1` does contain `Column2`, and so the second batch can be compiled (and executed)

As to the final part of your question, I cannot reproduce your experience.

Comment: I don't get answer for my question.

Comment: when I drop column Column2 and trying execute

alter table Table1 add Column2 VARCHAR(20) NULL
update Table1 set Column2='a'
I get a success message (1 row(s) affected) Why? where lose "batch" ?

Comment: That's the bit I said I couldn't reproduce. Can you create a single, coherent script that demonstrates the issue, rather than scraps of code interspersed with narrative about other actions (E.g. there's no explicit `ALTER TABLE` to drop `Column2` in your examples, currently).

Answer (score 1):

During your First Try (Case 1)

```
alter table Table1 add Column2 VARCHAR(20) NULL --Line 1
update Table1 set Column2='a' --Line 2
```

i) column2 added to the table
ii)There was no column by name column2 in table for a update statement(no statistics for the column name column2 while executing as a batch) so SQL Server aborts the batch. (Column added in that batch are not taken into account for the subsequent statements in the batch so update failed)
Note: Added column also rolledback since batch failed

You dropped the column meanwhile in other session

```
alter table Table1 drop column column2
```

During your Second Try (Case 2)

```
alter table Table1 add Column2 VARCHAR(20) NULL --Line 1
update Table1 set Column2='a' --Line 2
```

i) column2 added since it is not in table now
ii)There was a column by name column2 was exist in table(it considered old statistics while executing as a batch) so SQL Server tried and succeeded. (So both statements are committed)

You drop the column again in some session

```
alter table Table1 drop column column2
```

Now try this add brand new column(Case 3)

```
alter table Table1 add Column3 VARCHAR(20) NULL --Line 1
update Table1 set Column2='a' --Line 2
```

i) column3 added since it is not in table now
ii)update statement failed since there is no column by name column2

Here i got one doubt while exploring your scenario.(column3 added to the table though in a batch, other statement failed.)

I am expecting SQL Server to abort the whole batch but it dint. It added the column column3 into the table.

Just wondering how in case 1) it reverts the whole batch and now(in case 3) it is not.

Comment: I am already dropped statistic from table statistics, but no result

Answer (score 0):

I learned what it was.
We must call 
 **DBCC FREEPROCCACHE**
to get again non worked code (without **GO**)

```
alter table Table1 add Column2 VARCHAR(20) NULL
update Table1 set Column2='a'
```